# Rigtht way to implement Aysnchronous Delegate Methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, design-patterns, asynchronous, delegates

Consider the following situation.

```
-(void) foo {

    Object * obj = [[Object alloc] init];

    obj.delegate = self;

    [obj excuteAsync];
}

-(void) delegateMethodReturned {
    // do something
}
```

Here executeAync returns aynchronously after sometime. Thus we cannot release obj safely. What is the best design pattern to implement such a situation without declaring obj as an iVar.

Thanks

Comment: The best design pattern is to make it an iVar. You "have" to, because it lasts for longer than foo. Simple. It is not self-contained within foo, so it should not be local to foo. Simple. Just because you instantiate something inside foo, it does not mean that it conceptually exists only within foo, as in this case it is much bigger than just foo. Simple!  The case is so clear-cut I'd say you "must" make it an iVar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can target iOS4 you could circumvent the asynchronous callback using blocks and GCD.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
    Object * obj = [[Object alloc] init];
    [obj excuteSync];
    // do something
    [obj release];
});
```

I have found this helpful in some situations but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hey.. I think that is a good answer..Never tried that out..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) delegateMethodReturned: (Object *)obj {
  [obj release];
}
```

However, the static analyser will complain about that, because it thinks you leaked `obj` in `-foo`, which you did.

Comment: Actually that is why i said 'safe' way to release.

Comment: @Mahadevan: there's nothing "unsafe" about that approach. The tool has a known false positive problem (check the LLVM bugzilla).

Comment: This should work if you can guarantee that the delegate method will be called, and only called once. I wouldn't trust myself never to make a change that would lead to the delegate method being called more than one time or not at all. I would recommend using an ivar.